# Masonry.js column numbers change on browser width

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

How is it possible to change the number of columns in Masonry on browser windows width?

Something like this:

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { 2 columns }
@media all and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { 3 columns }
@media all and (min-width : 1024px) { 4 columns }
```

```js
$('#content .home').masonry({
    //options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : function(containerWidth) {
        return containerWidth / 2; 
    },
    isAnimated: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var CollManag = (function() {
    var $ctCollContainer = $('#grid'),
    collCnt = 1,
    init = function() {
        changeColCnt();
        initEvents();
        initPlugins();
    },
    changeColCnt = function() {
        var w_w = $(window).width();
        if( w_w <= 480 ) n = 1;
        else if( w_w <= 700 ) n = 2;
        else n = 3;
    },
    initEvents = function() {
        $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
            changeColCnt();
        });
    },
    initPlugins = function() {
        $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.box_item',
                columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / n;
                },
                isAnimated : true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 400
                }
            });
        });

    };
    return { init: init };
})();
CollManag.init();
});
```

Or

```
$( window ).load( function()
{
    var columns    = 3,
        setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 700 ? 3 : $( window ).width() > 480 ? 2 : 1 };

    setColumns();
    $( window ).resize( setColumns );

    $( '#grid' ).masonry(
    {
        itemSelector: '.box_item',
        gutterWidth: 0,
        isAnimated: true,
        columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns; }
    });
});
```